# Tooltip of a List of checkboxes in silverlight

Tags: xaml, silverlight, data-binding, listbox, tooltip

I want to display a list of checkboxes within a tooltip on Silverlight when the mouse hovers on an image.
The data is a list of string properties.
The problem: The checkbox text content disappears, only the checked boxes appear.
How to show both the box and its text content? Thanks.

[Tooltip display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjVxW.png)

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip >
            <ToolTip d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Data}">
                    <ListBox x:Name="LstTemp">

                    <!--<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding Input}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>-->

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  IsChecked="true" IsEnabled="False" Content="{Binding Input}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </ToolTip>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

The code behind

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property Data1 As String
    Public Property Data2 As String
    Public Property Input As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

Comment: Can you actually interact with stuff in tooltips? That's not how I remember it. Also, why do you use `CheckBox`es in a `ListBox`? `ListBox` is an interactive container, `CheckBox` is an interactive item. `ItemsControl` itself would be better so that the container doesn't interfere with the item.

Comment: In the commented section of the XAML code I get the items with their text from the list of string properties but not the checkbox. With the checkbox section I get the checkbox but not the text of the checkbox (the content) see photo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, here is the code for a dynamic list of checkboxes within a tooltip

```
            <Image Height="114" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129,48,0,0" Name="Image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Source="/Tooltip1;component/Images/Desert.jpg" >

<ToolTipService.ToolTip >
            <ToolTip d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Data}">
                <ListBox x:Name="LstTemp">
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                            <Grid Margin="2">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <CheckBox IsChecked="true" IsEnabled="false"/>
                                                <ContentPresenter
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>

                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>
            </ToolTip>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    </Image>
```